# How to create triggered journey on custom object creation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

We've salesforce marketing cloud and sales cloud integration. We're using a custom object "Enquiry" (child object of Lead) in sales cloud.

I want to create a journey, whenever a new Enquiry (custom object) is created it should entered into triggered journey.

Please let me know how to design this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, but easiest is probably configuring a new Journey, so it would react in real-time.

1. When you start setting up your Journey Entry Event, then select **Salesforce Data** as the source.
2. When you start defining the Entry Event, select **Salesforce Data** and click Next.
3. Find your Enquiry object in the list.
4. Select who should enter to the Journey, select **Lead ID (Lead)** and click Next.
5. Now simply select '**Is Created**' checkbox and if you prefer, also add in some additional criteria by selecting '**Meets Specific Entry Criteria**'.
6. On the Filter Criteria step you can add additional parameters to
   check on related records, such as your Lead, that it *actually* has an
   Email address on it, or that you have the permission to contact .
7. On the Entry Data step you find the fields you want to use in your Journey (decision splits for an example) and in personalization and add them to the Selected Entry Data list.
8. Finally on the Summary tab you verify everything is correct and hit Done.

Comment: Hi ASHISH, this is exactly what my steps describe. However the person that enters to the Journey can only be either a User, Lead or a Contact record via Salesforce Entry Event. If you want to use some custom records that are not Leads or Contacts, then you'll need to use Synchronised Data Extensions to create a Filtered / Query based Data Extension and define a new attribute as the SubscriberKey. Be aware that this way you cannot use majority of the cross-clouds functionality though, including seeing Individual Email Results and the likes in Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Successfully implemented in journey builder now.